# What value of b make the following matrix diagonalisable

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    1 & b  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

It seems like there's no two distinct eigenvalues to make it diagonalisable. Can anyone confirm that is true?

Comment: What did you get when you tried to compute the Jordan form?

Comment: We can't confirm whether you've done it right if you don't show is what you've done. What are the eigenvalues? How did you find them? Also, note that a matrix with two equal eigenvalues could still be diagonalizable, just look at the identity matrix.

Comment: (1-t)(b-t)+1, and no matter what I tried to substitute, it will always come out as t^2-nt+n, hence I couldn't find the eigenvalues without using quadratic formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of the matrix is

$$p(\lambda)=(b-\lambda)(1-\lambda) + 1 = \lambda^2 -(b+1)\lambda + (b+1)$$

with determinant

$$\Delta=(b+1)^2 - 4(b+1)= (b+1)(b-3)$$

When $\Delta>0$ we have two distinct real eigenvalues, so the matrix is diagonalisable, which happens for $b>3$ and $b < -1$. For $-1 < b < 3$ we have no real eigenvalues (so not diagonalisable). Leaves to check $b=-1$ and $b=3$. $b=3$ leaves $\lambda =2$ (double multiplicity, while we have one eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$). $b=-1$ is a similar failure.

So my conclusion is that we *can* diagonalise the matrix, e.g. for $b>3$ and $b < -1$.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how do you get determinant (b+1)^2 - 4(b+1)?

Comment: square of the coefficient of $\lambda$, $b+1$, minus $4$ times the coefficient of $\lambda^2$ ($1$) times the constant term $(b+1)$. @Complicated In general, the determinant of $a_2t^2 + a_1t+ a_0$ is $4a_1^2 - 4a_0a_2$.

Comment: Oh, just realize what you meant was b^2-4ac, thank you!